# Data won't be fetched from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, fetch

When attempting to pull in data from a mysql database, I'm getting nothing.

Just simply "ID: "

Code:

```
<?php
require 'db/connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM offenses";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result));{
    echo "<br />";

    echo "ID : ". $row['id'];
}

mysqli_close($db);


?>
```

Comment: remove ; from while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result));

Comment: Thank you! I can't answer my own question for 8 hours.. Can you submit an answer and then i can mark it as correct?

Comment: ok submitted the answer !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `;` from `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result));`

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the `;` from the while statement

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<br />";

    echo "ID : ". $row['id'];
}
```